# How to open specific view controller when user clicks on Notification comes from Xtify?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, xtify

I am using xtify for receiving push notification. I am using some tag to get push notification when tag will we active it receive notification and open my tag related view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a url as an extra property of the push notification and make your app respond to a url scheme.

For instance, you add an extra parameters *url* in your push notification dictionary with the value

*myapp://ViewController1?bar=foo*

In your app delegate, you will then parse the url and Instantiate *ViewController1* and set the property *foo* to *bar*.

To help you with the parsing, you could use this [routing library](https://github.com/joeldev/JLRoutes).

As a bonus, you could make your app respond to incoming url using your custom scheme as it would reuse the same logic as for the push notification routing. See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html) to add custom url support to your app.